# 407 Proxy Authentication Access Is Denied

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax call and getting this error. But this URL works absolutely fine through firefox rest client.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://bi-helixa.verisk.com/SpotfireWeb/Logout.aspx",
    type: "POST",

});
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy in your network?

Comment: How can I figure that out?

Comment: Ask your administrator?